# The correct way to include jquery in a module's form

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I'm trying to use jquery in a form of mine that is rendered via the form api.

How i'm getting jquery to work now is like so

```
$form['raf_raffle_name'] = array(
    '#type' => "textfield",
    "#prefix" => "<h5>Raffle information</h5><hr>",
    "#title" => "Raffle Name:",
    "#required" => TRUE,
    "#attached" => array(
        'js' => array(
            "$path/jquery.js", "$path/test1.js"
        ),
    )
);
```

well it works, but i'm not sure if its the right way. Is there a better way? I'm inclined to ask after i saw the 'library' attribute which is supposed to load up certain javascript plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to manually include jQuery:

"When JavaScript is added to a page through Drupal, jQuery is automatically added to the page."

-- https://www.drupal.org/node/171213